# Any Dice Help - Reroll 1's in dice pools

Tags: anydice

I have made some progress in AnyDice showing the probability for dice resolution system in the RPG system I've been working on. Here is the link to what I have so far: https://anydice.com/program/16e4a

I need particular help on when a roll gets a 2 or 3 that that die can be rerolled once. I am interested to see how this alters the probability of success.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This a good first question. Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `ROLL: NDICEd{{1,4..6}:3, {1..6}}`

Why it works is explained in [4d6 reroll 1's and 2's and drop lowest can anydice do this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115193/4d6-reroll-1s-and-2s-and-drop-lowest-can-anydice-do-this/115232#115232).

Also, you can replace your function with `SUCCESS: [count {4..6} in ROLL] > NTARGET`.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks! https://anydice.com/program/16e74